# google maps not rendering while driving android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am facing an issue of google maps rendering maps while driving it's not updating the map fast

I have tried several ways to counter this but no result

Thank you in advance

[image: Screenshot while driving]

Comment: Could you please provide a sample application for us to check?

Comment: I have found the solution, this issue was fixed by Google in the latest google maps API for android "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1" or above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved in google maps latest version 18 or above

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext(), MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST, this);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```